# F1/F0.5 score as eval_metric in XGBClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgbclassifier

I'm performing a classification task using XGBClassifier - I want to reuse sklearn's functionalities as much as possible. Especially I'm interested in defining my custom scorer using [f_beta](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html#sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score) function to define f0.5 score.

When I run the following code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=5, 
                    learning_rate=0.25,
                    objective='binary:logistic',
                    use_label_encoder=False,
                    eval_metric=make_scorer(fbeta_score(beta=0.5)),
                    )
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: fbeta_score() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred'
```

Also, following this part of [XGBoost documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html) I simplified the case just to use a predefined, ready `f1_score` metric: `eval_metric=f1_score` but XGBClassifier switches back to log-loss one.

How can I implement my customised metric in the appropriate way?

Answer (score 0):

if you check the documentation you cannot use with `eval_metric` creating you own metric but the one listed in the documentation

But if you want to optimize I think you can precise a custom metric in gridsearchCV with **scoring**